# Show error after button click Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, buttonclick

After my button click, I would check if my text fields are not empty. My check works, but if I show my message it's show for a few seconds. Probably the duration of my button click. Here is some code I've tried.

```
<form>
    <div id="errorblock">
        <p id="errortext">Error.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- here are my input fields-->

    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

This is where I add my event listener after initialisation of the page:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    sendEmail();
});

function sendEmail() {

    //check if all fields are fill in. If not do this code;
    document.getElementById("errortext").innerHTML = "Fill in all the fields please.";

    var errorblock = document.getElementById("errorblock");       
    errorblock.style.visibility = "visible";
    errorblock.style.height = "46px";
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default [HTMLButtonElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement) has `type="submit"`. It means that on button click the form is submitted. You need to make sure you prevent this submission in case of errors in the form. For example by calling `preventDefault` methods of the event object:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (!sendEmail()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

function sendEmail() {

    //check if all fields are fill in. If not do this code;
    document.getElementById("errortext").innerHTML = "Fill in all the fields please.";

    var errorblock = document.getElementById("errorblock");
    errorblock.style.visibility = "visible";
    errorblock.style.height = "46px";

    // if there are errors return false
    // return true if input is correct
    return false;
}
```

Also I recommend to listen `onsubmit` event on the form instead of button click event:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    if (!sendEmail()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```